# Project a particle to the surface of a cube

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to implement cloth collision with objects, the cloth is represented using a spring-mass system, it's made up of a known number of particles, each particle has a vec3 as its position, the cloth should take the shape of the object that it collides with, so far I was able to project the cloth to the surface of ball using this function:

```
void ballCollision(const Vec3 center, const float radius)
{
    std::vector<Particle>::iterator particle;
    for (particle = particles.begin(); particle != particles.end(); particle++)
    {
        Vec3 v = (*particle).getPos() - center;
        float l = v.length();
        if (v.length() < radius) // if the particle is inside the ball
        {
            // offset position simply adds a vec3 to the particles position
            (*particle).offsetPos(v.normalized()*(radius - l)); // project the particle to the surface of the ball
        }
    }
}
```

but that's easy since the distance between the center of the ball and its surface is constant, unlike the distance between the center of a cube and its surface.

All I know about the cube is its center and the length of its edge, how do I project the particles of the cloth to the surface of the cube?

Comment: You need to know the cube's orientation.

Answer (score 0):

A cube is 6 planes with constraints for each plane. You can use Ray intersection from point to plane.

Iterate across the planes with your Ray steps from the corners.